# How do I clear the SMB credential cache?

Tags: networking, samba, smb

I used smbclient *[...]* **-U** once, and I entered some network credentials.

Now when I browse the server with Thunar (xfce file manager), it remembers the credentials I entered. How can I make the computer forget every username/domain/password I ever entered?

---

Xubuntu 11.10, most recent samba/everything updates.

Comment: As far as I know smbclient doesn't do any caching of credentials, nor does it support anything like gnomekeyring. Are you sure it's not just using your UNIX username?

Comment: @jelmer I'm sorry I didn't make this clear enough. `smbclient` itself does indeed not remember the credentials by itself it seems, however, after I entered them _once in smbclient_, Thunar (xfce file manager) remembers them. So the caching is probably done by something other than smbclient. Sorry, the lack of information was my fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a Linux box booted at the moment, so I can't provide specific instructions - but Gnome (and probably XFCE) maintain a 'keyring' of credentials. Have you tried looking around for your desktop environment's keyring and clearing that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply provide the credentials in the command, e.g.

```
smbclient //server/share -U USERNAME%PASSWORD
```